# Google API Client hasConnectedAPI Not Working

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

I've been working with the Google Play Services library alongside Google Fit for awhile and suddenly, the workflow authentication flow I have does not work anymore.

Once the user has selected their Google account through the API Client it registers as connected. However, the APIs included in the builder aren't being shown as connected through the hasConnectedAPI function.

The specific function I'm calling is `apiClient.hasConnectedApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)`

Here is the code I'm using to create the builder:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestServerAuthCode(activity.getString(R.string.web_client_id), false)
        .requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE), new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE),
                new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE), new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
        .build();
return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(failedListener)
        //.addApi(Plus.API)
        .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
        .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
        .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
        .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
        .addApi(Fitness.BLE_API)
        .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
        .build();
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippets for where you test the connected-ness of the various APIs, as well as your connectionCallbacks and failedListener? Although I don't use the GoogleSignInOptions.Builder or as many APIs as you, I have run into and trouble-shot tons of problems, ranging from the Fit API hanging while connecting or the connection failing.

Comment: So I had been building and running my app from a secondary computer (laptop). For whatever reason, the authentication flow worked when I switched back to my main development computer. The HASH/Keystore may not have been registered on the secondary computer (although it's worked before) and usually either an error or message comes up if it isn't. Works now though